# How to avoid the select n + 1 problem in nested entities

Tags: entity-framework

Given the following code:

```
var persons = context.PERSONs.Select(
    x =>
    new
    {
        personId = x.PERSON_ID,
        personName = x.PERSON_NAME,
        items = x.ITEMs.Select(
            y =>
            new
            {
                itemID = y.ITEM_ID,
                itemName = y.ITEM_NAME,
                properties = y.PROPERTies.Select(
                    z =>
                    new
                    {
                        z.PROPERTY_ID,
                        z.PROPERTY_NAME
                    }
                )
            }
        )
    }
).ToList();
```

How can I avoid select n + 1 problems with it? Tried .Include("ITEMs").Include("ITEMs.PROPERTies") but it didn't help. Would expect a single query with 2 left outer joins.

Note - would like a generic answer because I'm working on an OData background where it's hard to craft queries for each entity by hand

-edit-

Database: MS SQL Server

Entity Framework version: 6

Can confirm that all properties are simple mapped properties (ints and strings actullay, no functions nor computed values)

Comment: What database are you running against, and have you inspected the SQL when this runs? is this EF6 or EF Core? Also, assuming the provided code has been simplified from your real code, can you verify that *all* properties referenced in the `.Select` expressions are simple, mapped properties and not computed values or involve function calls from your code? (EF Core won't throw errors and will prematurely execute queries if it encounters code it cannot translate to SQL)

Comment: @StevePy updated my question with clarifications

Comment: What is the actual behavior you are seeing?  Can you enhance your question with a simplified repro? That query looks like it should generate a single SQL query.

Comment: What SQL queries are you seeing being run? The above example would generate a single SQL statement with joins to populate your returned model. If you are seeing multiple queries being generated then we would need to see the actual model being selected and the SQL that is generated identifying any unexpected statements to work out what might be happening.